# How to Populate XML in Telerik Tree View using Asp.net with C# 

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc-3

Hi I am using a **web application with MVC3**. I am new to this MVC3 with **telerik treeview** control. Can any one tell me some examples for **populating XML file into Telerik tree view** using MVC pattern?

My XML File code is:

```
<Department>
  <Employee>
     <Salary value="20000">
     <Designation value="Developer">
  </Employee>
  <Experience>
     <Grade value="G2">
     <Age value="26">
     <YearsOfExperience value=4>
  </Experience>
  <Reward>
     <Rating value="3">
  </Reward>
</Department>
```

This is my XML file content. Here **Department** is my **root node** and **Employee,Experience** and **Reward** are the **same level** nodes.Salary,designation,grade, age and rating are the **child nodes** of the above nodes.

Now I want to populate this XML file into Telerik Tree View control using MVC.
can anyone please tell me the process with Controller, View ,CSHTML ?

How can i achieve this implementation?

Answer (score 0):

The LoadContentFile method expects the XML to be in a predefined format specific to RadTreeView:

```
    <Tree>
   <Node Text="North America" Expanded="True" Value="1">
     <Node>
        <Node>
        </Node>
     </Node>
   </Node>
 </Tree>
```